# How to use $compile in Angular to export HTML to external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an issue where I can't send compiled HTML to an external function. I can do it if I do everything within the Angular app space. But when I send my compiled result to an external function it is not rendering anymore. Anyone got any idea why this isn't working, or even better a solution how to make it work?

My external function (exists outside of the angular app)

```
<script>
  var ext = {};

  ext.addFunction(elem) {
    $('#eventListExtFunction').html(elem);
  }
</script>
```

My directive (calls the external function with the compiled HTML)

```
var eventListElem = angular.element('<event-list-ext></event-list-ext>'),
    extElem = $compile(eventListElem)(scope);

// Add to external through function
ext.addFunction(extElem);
```

See this plunker for more info about what I am trying to accomplish:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HkCGFsBX751oPyXgzKEn?p=preview

Comment: there is an error saying `ReferenceError: ext is not defined`! what is `ext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your syntax. There's a problem on the third line:

```
var ext = {};

ext.addFunction(elem) {
  $('#eventListExtFunction').html(elem);
}
```

when it should be:

```
var ext = {};

ext.addFunction = function(elem) {
  $('#eventListExtFunction').html(elem);
}
```

Comment: @KungWaz I screw that kind of thing up all the time :-) one thing that might help is JSLint. It'll check that kind of stuff.